# Converting Binary Values to Points

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion, binary

I searched a lot for this question but couldn't find a similar question.

How can I convert my binary values to points. The output of the code I wrote is below, I wrote my expectation also below.

```
firstsolution = {0, 6, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2}
firstsolutionbinary = IntegerDigits[firstsolution, 2, 3]
firstpointN8 = Table[Point[firstsolutionbinary[]], {1}]
```

**Output:**

> {Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1,
> 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}[]]}

**My expectation:**

> {Point[{0, 0, 0}], Point[{1, 1, 0}], Point[{1, 0, 0}],   Point[{1, 1,
> 1}], Point[{0, 0, 1}], Point[{0, 1, 1}],   Point[{1, 0, 1}], Point[{0,
> 1, 0}]}

**Possible Solution: (it doesn't work)**

```
For[i = 0, i < 8, i++, 
 print (Table[Point[firstsolutionbinary[[i]]], {i}])]
```

Comment: `Point /@ firstsolutionbinary`

Comment: `Thread[Point@firstsolutionbinary]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map[Point, firstsolutionbinary]

(* {Point[{0, 0, 0}], Point[{1, 1, 0}], Point[{1, 0, 0}], Point[{1, 1, 1}], Point[{0, 0, 1}], Point[{0, 1, 1}], Point[{1, 0, 1}], Point[{0, 1, 0}]} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
firstsolution = {0, 6, 4, 7, 1, 3, 5, 2};
firstsolutionbinary = IntegerDigits[firstsolution, 2, 3];
```

As shown in the documentation for [`Point`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html), `Point` can take as its argument a collection of points. That is, `Point` acts as if it had the attribute `Listable`.

```
Graphics3D[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[firstsolutionbinary]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Point @@@ firstsolutionbinary
```

> 

```
{Point[0, 0, 0], Point[1, 1, 0], Point[1, 0, 0], Point[1, 1, 1], 
 Point[0, 0, 1], Point[0, 1, 1], Point[1, 0, 1], Point[0, 1, 0]}
```